# ElasticSearch should query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create ElasticSearch query which would be the same as this SQL query

```
select *
from main.adverts
where user_id = 4
      and 
      (title ilike '%продать / купить%'
        or description ilike '%продать / купить%'
      )
```

My attempt is:

```
{
  "query" :{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "user.id" : {
            "value" : 4,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "title" : {
                  "query" : "продать",
                  "operator" : "OR",
                  "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard" : {
                "title" : {
                  "wildcard" : "купить*",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "disable_coord" : false,
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "description" : {
                  "query" : "продать",
                  "operator" : "OR",
                  "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard" : {
                "description" : {
                  "wildcard" : "купить*",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "disable_coord" : false,
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "disable_coord" : false,
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly. As the result of this query I got records which doesn't contain phrase "продать / купить".

I think that problem is in the "should" part of ElasticSearch query but can't get where is particular.

Could you point me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found solution

```
{
  "from" : 0, "size" : 60,
  "_source" : ["title", "description"],
  "query" :{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "user.id" : {
            "value" : 4,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "title" : {
                  "query" : "продать",
                  "operator" : "OR",
                  "prefix_length" : 0,
                  "max_expansions" : 50,
                  "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
                  "lenient" : false,
                  "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard" : {
                "title" : {
                  "wildcard" : "купить*",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should" : [
            {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                  {
                    "match" : {
                      "description" : {
                        "query" : "продать",
                        "operator" : "OR",
                        "prefix_length" : 0,
                        "max_expansions" : 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
                        "lenient" : false,
                        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard" : {
                      "description" : {
                        "wildcard" : "купить*",
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "disable_coord" : false,
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "disable_coord" : false,
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "disable_coord" : false,
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```